# How can I create 2-colored squares to use as PlotLegends?

Tags: plotting, legending

I'd like to generate a square similar to the one that is shown below, but instead of that, I would like solid colors on both sides, separated maybe by a thin black line in the diagonal, if that's possible.

```
LinearGradientImage[{{Left, Top}, {Right, Bottom}} -> {Blue, Red}]
```

[image: Output of the code. This looks like the marker I want, but it must be adapted as explained in the text]

Then, I would like to use it as a marker for a legend in a plot. For instance, I could use something like the following code, but it still remains to be adapted for our purposes, of course.

```
SwatchLegend[{Red,Green,Blue},{"a","b","c"},LegendMarkerSize->15,LegendMarkers->"FadingRectangle",LegendFunction->"Frame"]
```

Is there a way to achieve both things in a simple manner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To draw the line through the diagonal that scales is tricky, so instead I used a solid rectangle in the background.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
g[c1_, c2_, cbkg_] := Graphics[{
    {cbkg, Rectangle[]}
    , {FaceForm[c1], EdgeForm[c1], 
     Triangle[{{0, 0.05}, {0, 1}, {0.95, 1}}]}
    , {FaceForm[c2], EdgeForm[c2], 
     Triangle[{{0.05, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 0.95}}]}
    }
   , AspectRatio -> Automatic
   ];
```

**Usage:**

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}}
 , PlotMarkers -> {
   {g[Red, Green, Black], Offset[10]}
   , {g[Cyan, Orange, Black], Offset[20]}
   , {g[Purple, Green, Black], Offset[30]}
   }
 , PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.1], Scaled[0.1]}
 , PlotLegends -> Placed[SwatchLegend[Automatic
    , {"a", "b", "c"}
    , LegendMarkerSize -> {10, 20, 30}
    , LegendMarkers -> {
      g[Red, Green, Black]
      , g[Cyan, Orange, Black]
      , g[Purple, Green, Black]
      }
    , LegendFunction -> "Frame"
    , LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn"
    ]
   , {0.20, 0.8}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great and it has a few little aesthetic details that I really like.

Answer (score 9):

```
marker[color1_, color2_, size_ : 10] := 
  Graphics[{color1, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}], color2, 
    Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}], FaceForm[None], 
    CapForm["Butt"], Thickness[.04], Black, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}, 
   ImageSize -> size];

ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {marker[Blue, Red], marker[Green, Orange]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Data 1", "Data 2"}]
```

[image: Plot]

To use it in `PointLegend`:

```
PointLegend[{0, 0}, {"Data 1", "Data 2"}, 
 LegendMarkers -> {marker[Blue, Red], marker[Green, Orange]}]
```

[image: Legend]

Answer (score 7):

You can use the directive [`LinearGradientFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearGradientFilling.html) construct a legend with desired markers:

```
SwatchLegend[{LinearGradientFilling[{Blue, Red}, -Pi/4], 
  LinearGradientFilling[{Green, Orange}, -Pi/4]}, 
 {"a", "b"}, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> 50, LegendFunction -> "Frame"]
```

[image]

Use the form `LinearGradientFilling[positions -> colors]` to avoid blending of colors:

```
SwatchLegend[
 {LinearGradientFilling[{0, 1/2, 1/2, 1} -> {Red, Red,   Blue, Blue}, -Pi/4], 
 LinearGradientFilling[{0, 1/2, 1/2, 1} -> {Green, Green, Orange, Orange}, -Pi/4]},
 {"a", "b"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 50, LegendFunction -> "Frame"]
```

[image]

You can also define custom markers using `LinearGradientFilling`:

```
lgfMarkers[colors_] := 
   Graphics[{LinearGradientFilling[colors, -Pi/4], Rectangle[]}]
```

***Examples:***

```
lgfMarkers[{Blue, Red}]
```

[image]

```
lgfMarkers[{0, 1/2, 1/2, 1} -> {Blue, Blue, Red, Red}]
```

[image]

Slightly modify to add a diagonal line with default color black:

```
lgfMarkers2[colorlist_, linecolor_ : 
   Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[2], CapForm["Butt"]]] := 
 Graphics[{{LinearGradientFilling[colorlist, -Pi/4], Rectangle[]}, 
   linecolor, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}]

lgfMarkers2[{0, 1/2, 1/2, 1} -> {Blue, Blue, Red, Red}]
```

[image]

Use the optional second argument to specify the diagonal line color:

```
lgfMarkers2[{0, 1/2, 1/2, 1} -> {Blue, Blue, Red, Red}, Directive[Thick, White]]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[{{2, 1, 3}, {3, 2, 1}}, 
 Joined -> True, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{lgfMarkers[{Blue, Red}], .07}, {lgfMarkers[{Green, 
      Orange}], .07}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"data A", "data B"}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]]
```

[image]

Comment: I think kglr is the best and most Intelligent user in stack exchange

Comment: how we can change the rectangular to circular? I changed the "Rectangle" in lgfMarkers but no event has happened!!

Comment: @monfneg, much as I cannot agree with you, I appreciate  your kind words:) To _change the rectangular to circlular_, replace `Rectangle[]` with `Disk[]`.

Comment: Thnkxxxx so much